# What is the difference between declaring a variable in a header instead of the source file (cpp/h)

Tags: c++

Are there any difference between ***declaring variables in a header*** and ***declaring variables in a source code***? e.g *perfomance*,*securities*

Comment: Header is source code?

Comment: Is header a source code?

Comment: No. The pre-processor includes the header in the source file, so declaring it in the header is exactly equivalent to declaring it individually in every file the header file is included in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference at all.  Except they are best written in such a way that it supports:

- Multiple modules may include the header to share the data structures
- and share the function declarations.
- A header is often written so that it doesn't declare its contents multiple times.

  ```
  #ifndef __THIS_HEADER_H
   #define __THIS_HEADER_H  1
   ....  (content of header which is protected from multiple insertions)
  #endif
  ```

A module may include a `.c` file, but this is rare (and non-recommended) usage:

a.c:

```
 #define PERSONALITY   1
 #include "main_logic.c"
```

b.c:

```
 #define PERSONALITY   2
 #include "main_logic.c"
```

main_logic.c:

```
 #if PERSONALITY == 1
 int main (void)
 {
    printf ("personality 1\n");
 }
 #endif

 #if PERSONALITY == 2
 int main (void)
 {
    printf ("personality 2\n");
 }
 #endif
```

Answer (score -2):

Declaring variables in the header makes them available to all files that include this header using `#include<...>`. Declaring it in the cpp file makes them available to the code in this file only.

This is because of the way **cpp** and **h** files work together.

- The **h** file always includes the **cpp** file. No include statement is necessary here.
- Other files including the **h** file will get what's in the **h** file, not the **cpp** file, therefore variables declared there are out of scope.

The **h** file contains all the declarations, while the corresponding **cpp** file should contain the code for these declarations.

**Please** (also for future readers) note that using only **h** files in order to avoid a seemingly complex situation is very bad practice, because you would then not be using a very good language feature and it would make it (with the exception of using classes) impossible to separate private from public functions and variables.

Also, on another note: **h** files are distributed, while their code (which is in the **cpp** file is compiled into a binary. So for the sake of not reveling your code to everyone and keeping the header files small, you should split this appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by "The h file always includes the cpp file"?

Comment: `#include<...>` should only be used for standard headers.  `#include "..."` should be used for user-written headers.

Comment: @M.M is that a guideline somewhere? I don't follow it. The only difference is `#include "..."` searches the file's directory for the header before searching the regular include paths.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe that's put with weird words, but it's there so the OP can understand it since he/she has struggle understanding the concept of h and cpp.

Comment: @Kevin it's what the C++ standard says

Comment: Actually I asked because I wanted to know if it does affects performance and such

Comment: @M.M Can you show me a link? I don't think the standard says anything about this. And @bytecode77 that quote is likely to confuse the OP as the only things headers include are what they `#include`.

Comment: @UnsolvedRubiks It doesn't affect performance at all. It's all about coding style, which is very important, too - especially if you think of big projects or projects made within a team.

Comment: THIS IS WRONG. "makes them available to the code in this file only" Make a class idk.cpp and make a public int num. Include idk.cpp in your main.cpp and call num.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks! My question is what misleading everyone it seems

Comment: The only difference between headers and cpp files is that by convention you should `#include` headers and compile cpp files.

Comment: @Kevin see [cpp.include]/2 and [cpp.include]/3 of the standard (or any non-ancient draft)

Comment: Any declaration in the header is accessible by the class that included that particular header,and so does a class/function that is defined in that header. This is what I understood from my learning. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @M.M: Those paragraphs do not say anything about standard headers vs user-written headers.

Comment: Let's not make this a clinical trial for rare diseases. This is simple. The whole concept of **cpp** and **h** is not that hard. I think I got it to a point. Any further suggestions?

Comment: `The h file always includes the cpp file.` This is beyond confusing, it's plain wrong. Technically wrong (what .cpp does <cstdio> include, for example?) and conceptually wrong (the header has no notion of the implementation, whether in one or more associated .cpp files).

Comment: @UnsolvedRubiks, classes does not include anything. `.cpp` files [usually] do.

Comment: `using only h files in order to avoid a seemingly complex situation is very bad practice` No. Just... just no. It may not always be the best idea, but calling it "bad practice"? No.